# www redirects to another directory in wordpress

Tags: plugins, redirect, htaccess, ssl

I am using Really Simple SSL plugin but I just noticed that whenever I type the [www.ozaro.com/mozaro](http://www.ozaro.com/mozaro) it automatically redirects to ozaro.com not ozaro.com/mozaro
So please help

Comment: You should speak to your host about this. It has nothing to do with WordPress.

Comment: Is the intention to redirect www to non-www? Does the "Really Simple SSL plugin" modify `.htaccess` (as you have tagged your question)? If so, then please edit your question to include your complete `.htaccess` file. "redirects to another directory in Wordpress" - you mean it redirects to the root (ie. home page)?